# Simulating a file upload in form data using MvcIntegrationTestingFramework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, form-data

I am using Steve Sanderson's MvcIntegrationTestingFramework and trying to simulate a post to an upload action. The second parameter is an object that is then converted into the name value pairs of the form data to be posted.

My test code is:

```
    [Test]
    [Category("integration")]
    public void UploadRunsCorrectlyWhenConfiguredFromApplicationStart()
    {
        var appHost = AppHost.Simulate("ingester");
        appHost.Start(session =>
                          {
                              var result = session.Post("upload/upload", 
                                           new
                                           {
                                             id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                                             file = ***Help here ***
                                            });
                              Assert.That(result.Response.StatusCode == 202);
                          } );
    }
```

The action is:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Upload(string id, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
         //Need file to not be null here
    }
```

My question is what should I put in ***Help here*** to have the file in action not appear as null?

Thanks :)